# Unix timestamp conversion to time with microsecond accuracy of seconds

Tags: python, timestamp, utc

I have 1000 of UYC timestamps in csv file, I want to convert it into date and time but I am only interested in second like

> Timestamps= 1666181576.26295,
> 1666181609.54292
>
> 19/10/2022 15:45:25.34568

from that I only have interest in 25.34568 seconds, also the numbers after points. How can I get this type of conversion in python? Mostly the search on the internet is interested in conversation from UTC to time and date but I also want precision in seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
from decimal import Decimal
ts = 1666181576.26295
timestamp = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts)
result = timestamp.second + Decimal(timestamp.microsecond)/1000000
print(result)
```

Will result in `56.26295`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datetime`,

```
from datetime import datetime
ts = 1666181576.26295
mseconds = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).microsecond
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I can see to do this is by splitting the timestamp to output everything from seconds onwards

```
timestamp = 1666181609.54292
temp = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)
output = str(temp)
print(output[17:])
```